# Powershell RegEx to include all output after a blank line

Tags: regex, powershell

I am running an exe that gets version info and outputs in the console.  I want to save the output into a variable but I need to exclude everything before a blank line and if possible remove the numbers at the beginning of output after the blank line but can do without. I figured that part would be easier but I can't figure out how to exclude things before a blank space.

This is my output.  It is returned as a string.

```
1     USB Receiver                                                                                                                                                        
1.1   M525 [off-line]
1.2   M525

1     RQR24.06_B0030
1.1   [off-line]
1.2   RQM27.02_B0028
```

So I have been trying to use patterns with select-string to only get the output after blank space but nothing has worked. I would like to ultimately just have the output without the leading numbers but have only been working on the blank line. so it looks like this:

```
1     RQR24.06_B0030
1.1   [off-line]
1.2   RQM27.02_B0028
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  Other ones I have tried keep adding a space to the top of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Multi-line input string.
$str = @'
1     USB Receiver
1.1   M525 [off-line]
1.2   M525

1     RQR24.06_B0030
1.1   [off-line]
1.2   RQM27.02_B0028
'@

# Get everything starting with the line after the first empty line,
# split it into individual lines, then remove the first token and subsequent
# whitespace from each line.
($str -split '\r?\n\r?\n', 2)[1] -split '\r?\n' -replace '^[^ ]+ +'
```

<sup>Note: If your input comes from a file, replace `$str` with `(Get-Content -Raw file.txt)`</sup>

The above yields (an array of strings, each element on its own line):

```
RQR24.06_B0030
[off-line]
RQM27.02_B0028
```

Explanation:

- `$str -split '\r?\n\r?\n', 2` splits the input into by the first two consecutive newlines (`\r?\n`, which matches both Windows-style CRLF and Unix-style LF-only newlines); `2` means that at most 2 tokens should be created.
- `(...)[1]` extracts the 2nd token, i.e., everything after the first empty lline.
- `-split '\r?\n'` splits the resulting token into individual lines
- `-replace '^[^ ]+ +'` effectively removes the 1st token as well as the whitespace that follows it from each line, leaving only the 2nd whitespace-separated token.